# Minimum EAGLE trace width for PCB etching with glossy paper and a cloth iron

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication, etching

What`s the minimum widht and clearence that's etchable using a photo paper and an iron? I've heard using too small clearence might mess the ink resulting in shorts. I want to have 20V@400mA, will 8mil of width and clearence work for such voltage and current, and will it be etchable?

Comment: It would be fairly easy to make a test pattern with a range of trace widths and clearances, transfer and etch and see what works well and what's too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a beginner, I'd suggest 40mil (1mm) traces with 10-20 mil gaps. PCB etching is an art more than a science and unless you have experience, I suggest you use the thickest traces you can. This way the chances that you have trace breaks are minimum.